Python Child class passing in values to parent class
so I have a parent class that has a function.
This parent class is making some API call with DEFAULT_URL. But in cases where DEFAULT_URL doesn't work and the call returns None, then I would like to use a fallback_url which is provided by ChildClass as CHILD_URL (if it exists).
This is how I'm currently trying to implement it which is the ChildClass passing in CHILD_URL as an argument in the ParentClass get_logs call, however I'm running into a problem since get_logs takes in any number of arguments. any pointers would be helpful. thanks!
File 1
DEFAULT_URL = "default url if the child doesn't provide a url"
class ParentClass(GrannyClass):
    name = "Base Application Logs"
        
    def get_logs(self, *, fallback_url=None) -> str:
         return some.API.call(DEFAULT_URL) or (fallback_url and some.API.call(fallback_url))

File 2
CHILD_URL = "url that exists that we want to use"
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    name = "Child Application Logs"
    def get_logs(self, *) -> str:
        return super().get_logs(CHILD_URL)
 


In ParentClass.get_logs(), fallback_url is a keyword-only parameter (since it follows a bare asterisk in the parameter list).  You would therefore have to write the call in ChildClass as super().get_logs(fallback_url=CHILD_URL).

what problem are you running into exactly?

ChildClass was passing in too many arguments to ParentClass.get_logs()

You need to pass the fallback_url argument by name to get_logs()
CHILD_URL = "url that exists that we want to use"

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    name = "Child Application Logs"

    def get_logs(self, *) -> str:
        return super().get_logs(fallback_url=CHILD_URL)

